# using php how to remember the text field and use cookie to show it next time going to the site?

Tags: php, forms, cookies, checkbox

ok I have simple text fields to input user/pass with a remember user check box but somehow I'm not sure what I did wrong that when I check the box the cookie will not be recreated and without cookie created when I revisit that site the user name won't show....this is what I have

```
function loginForm($userValue,$checkBox)
{

echo "<form action='index.php' method='get'>";
echo "<p>Username: <input type='text' name='user' value='$userValue' /></p>";
echo "<p>Password: <input type='password' name='pass' /></p>";
echo "<p>Remember my username next time I visit this site <input type='checkbox' name='remember'" . $checkBox . "/></p>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Log In' />";
echo "</form>";

}

if((!(isset($_GET["user"]))) && (!(isset($_COOKIE["username"]))))
{
    loginForm('','');
}
if(isset($_GET["remember"]))
{
    setcookie("username",$_GET["user"], time() + 60);
    loginForm($_COOKIE["username"],"checked");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have some logic errors. For one thing, you only check to see if you can fill out the form with a cookie whenever $_GET["remember"] has been set, which probably means the form was just submitted. Here's a modified version which might be a good start:

```
function loginForm($userValue,$checkBox)
{

echo "<form action='test.php' method='get'>";
echo "<p>Username: <input type='text' name='user' value='$userValue' /></p>";
echo "<p>Password: <input type='password' name='pass' /></p>";
echo "<p>Remember my username next time I visit this site <input type='checkbox' name='remember'" . $checkBox . "/></p>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Log In' />";
echo "</form>";

}

if (!isset($_GET["user"]) && !isset($_COOKIE["username"]))
{
    loginForm('','');
}
else if (isset ($_COOKIE["username"]))
{
    loginform ($_COOKIE["username"], '');
}
if (isset($_GET["remember"]))
{
    setcookie("username",$_GET["user"], time() + 60);
}
```

The big problem, though, is definitely that you're only allowing the cookie to work if the form was just submitted. The code I just posted works for me, and remembers my username.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your cookie with an expiration date of 60 seconds from the current time.  So it's probably just expired when you revisit the site.